# Independent objects needed when zipping into dict

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I have a list of items:

```
my_list = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

I need to convert this items into a dictionary (so I can access each element by it's name), and associate multiple counters to each element: counter1, counter2, counter3.

So I do the following:

```
counter_dict = {'counter1': 0, 'counter2': 0, 'counter3': 0}

my_dict = dict(zip(mylist, [counter_dict]*len(mylist)))
```

This way I obtain a nested dictionary

```
{
  'first': {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 0,
    'counter3': 0
  },
  'second': {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 0,
    'counter3': 0
  },
  'third': {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 0,
    'counter3': 0
  }
}
```

The problem here is that each counter dictionary is not independent, so when I update one counter, all of them are updated.

The following line not only updates the `counter2` of `second` but also updates `counter2` of `first` and `third`

```
my_dict['second']['counter2'] += 1


{
  'first': {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 1,
    'counter3': 0
  },
  'second': {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 1,
    'counter3': 0
  },
  'third': {
    'counter1': 0,
    'counter2': 1,
    'counter3': 0
  }
}
```

I am aware that by doing `[counter_dict]*len(mylist)` I am pointing all dictionaries to a single one.

Question is, how can I achieve what I need creating independent dictionaries?
At the end I need to:

- Acces each element of the list as a key
- For each element have multiple counters that I can update independently

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Eqomatic It says that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
my_dict = {k: counter_dict.copy() for k in my_list}
```

Instead of zipping values - it's enough to iterate over keys and copy your counters to values using dict compression.

But note, that this will work only with one level counter_dict. If needed nested dictionary - use `deepcopy` from `copy` package:

```
from copy import deepcopy
my_dict = {k: deepcopy(counter_dict) for k in my_list}
```

Another aproach - using `defaultdict` from `collections`, so you dont even need to create dictionary with predefined counters:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = {k: defaultdict(int) for k in my_list}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to copy a dict and copy its contents.

```
import copy
```

Instead of `[counter_dict]*len(mylist)`
use:

```
[copy.deepcopy(counter_dict) for _ in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension, not the `*` operator, and create a new dictionary for each element of the list.

```
my_dict = dict(zip(mylist, [dict(counter_dict) for _ in mylist])
```

Comment: `counter_dict` just maps strings to integers, so it isn't an immediate issue.

Comment: Oh right.  I was reading it as that whole dict in the question needed to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can go and make a function that will create a `counter_dict` whenever you want to assign one:

```
def create_counter_dict(length):
    return {'counter{}'.format(n+1) : 0 for n in range(length)}
```

Then when you want to assign a `counter_dict` to your `my_dict`:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(my_list, [create_counter_dict(3) for _ in range(len(my_list))]))
```

This way you don't have to make a copy of your dictionary, and you can alter this factory function to your needs.