# Appending values of a dictionary created using zip produces inconsistent results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a dictionary using the `dict(zip(..))` method, but I'm finding when appending its values i get differing results to appending a dictionary created in the default `x = {key: value}` or `dict([key, value], ..)` way..

Heres my example - i have a list of dictionaries:

```
my_values = [{"a": "blue", "b": "red"}, {"c": "blue", "d": "red"}]
```

I find the common colours from this list:

```
for item in my_values:

    data = []
    data.append(set(item.values()))

common_colors = data[0]

for item in data[1:]:
    common_colors &= item
```

And create a dictionary using zip from these **common colors**:

```
colors_a = dict(zip(common_colors, [
    []] * len(common_colors)))
```

If i append to this dictionary created via zip method:

```
# Colors A

for item in my_values:
    for key, value in item.iteritems():

        if value in colors_a:
            colors_a[value].append(key)
```

I get odd results:

```
print colors_a

# {'blue': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'red': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
```

When compared to if i create the dictionary using standard way:

```
colors_b = {"red": [], "blue": []}
```

And append to it:

```
# Colors B 

for item in my_values:
  for key, value in item.iteritems():

      if value in colors_b:
          colors_b[value].append(key)
```

I get the correct results:

```
print colors_b

# {'blue': ['a', 'c'], 'red': ['b', 'd']}
```

Even though before being appended the dictionaries are identical:

```
colors_a = dict(zip(common_colors, [
    []] * len(common_colors)))

colors_b = {"red": [], "blue": []}

print colors_a == colors_b 
# True
```

Any know any clues to what going on is much appreciated!

Comment: `[[]] * len(common_colors)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729978/independent-objects-needed-when-zipping-into-dict/46730104#46730104)

Comment: Ah yes - I understand! changed my code to use: [[] for i in range(len(common_colors))].